# Pure html css menu with horizontal submenu. Hover not working properly in IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, drop-down-menu, menu

Iam working on a pure html/css menu with horizontal submenu, but the hover is not working properly in Internet Explorer. When you hover over the submenu it disappears...
In Chrome and Firefox everything works fine.

Here is a jfiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/te5AU/2/

And here is the code:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="menu-holder">
        <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">item 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="active"><a class="test" href="#">This is the one</a>

                <ul class="submenu">
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 1</a>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">Submenu item 2</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 3</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">menu item 4</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <!-- menu-holder end -->
</div>
```

Here is the css:

```
 .wrapper {
     width:500px;
     height:500px;
     background:grey;
 }
 .menu-holder ul {
     margin: 2px 0 0px 25px;
     padding: 0;
     list-style-type: none;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li {
     position: relative;
     float: left;
     padding: 0px 10px 0 10px;
     margin: 0px 0px 100px 0px;
     border-left: 1px dotted white;
     line-height: 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li:hover > a {
     background-color: #025179;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li:hover ul {
     display: block;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li a {
     font-family: arial, sans-serif;
     font-size: 12px;
     font-weight: bold;
     display: block;
     color: white;
     text-decoration: none;
     padding: 15px 10px 15px 10px;
     -webkit-border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
     border-radius: 5px 5px 0px 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul {
     float: none;
     display: none;
     position: absolute;
     top: 40px;
     left: 0px;
     margin: -1px 0 0px 10px;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     white-space: nowrap;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul:hover {
     display: block;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li {
     position: static;
     float: none;
     display: inline;
     padding: 5px 10px 5px 10px;
     margin: 0px 0px 0px -10px;
     background-color: #025179;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li a {
     display: inline;
     margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
     padding: 0px 10px 0px 10px;
     font-weight: normal;
     -webkit-border-radius: 0;
     border-radius: 0;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li:first-of-type {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
     border-radius: 0px 0px 0px 5px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li ul li:last-of-type {
     -webkit-border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
     border-radius: 0px 5px 5px 0px;
 }
 .menu-holder ul li:first-of-type {
     border-left: none;
 }
```

Comment: Which versions of IE?

Comment: Tested on IE9, 8 and 7 (using your fiddle), could not reproduce the problem you are describing (though it does have other problems)

Comment: thats strange, is not working here on IE10, 9, and 8... How could that be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

li is not getting proper height in IE. U should remove

```
.menu-holder ul li { line-height: 0} //remove the css line-height: 0;
```

and then try.

Try this:
http://jsfiddle.net/te5AU/4/

Comment: Yes! thank you. That was it :) how did you find the solution so quickly? :)

Comment: nothing was quick, I just tried normal debugging to check whether there was height or not for li.

Glad I could be of help to you. :)

Answer (score 2):

HI i have some `changing` in you **css**

```
   .menu-holder > ul > li:hover > a {
         background-color: #025179;
     }


     .menu-holder ul li ul {
         float: none;
         display: none;
         position: absolute;
    margin:0;     top: 30px;padding:0;
         left: 10;
         white-space: nowrap;font-size:0;
     }

     .menu-holder ul li ul li {
         position: static;
         float: none;
         display: inline-block;
         padding:0;
         margin:0px;font-size:14px;
         background-color: #025179;
     }
     .menu-holder ul li ul li a {
         display:block;
         margin: 0 0px 0 0px;
         padding: 0 10px;
        line-height:30px;
         font-weight: normal;
         -webkit-border-radius: 0;
         border-radius: 0;
     }
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rohitazad/te5AU/6/)***